# Check for palindrome using recursion

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion

I have used the following code for checking whether a string is palindrome. However it is returning None when a string is palindrome.

```
def check(a):

    if len(a)==1 or len(a)==0:
        return True
    if a[0]==a[len(a)-1]:
        check(a[1:len(a)-1])
    else:
        return False




print check("radar")
```

Comment: Your algorithm is correct, but you need to `return check(a[1:len(a)-1])`.

Comment: @tpcat thanks.. It is resolved.

Comment: You can tighten your code a smidgeon by checking `len(a) < 2` in the first `if`, and by using negative indexing (`a[-1]` and `a[1:-1]`) in the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the result of the recursion in your function:

```
def check(a):
    # Base Case
    if len(a) < 2:
        return True

    # Recursive Call
    if a[0] == a[-1]:
        check(a[1:-1])
    else:
        return False

    return check(a[1:-1])

print check("radar")
```

### Bonus Info

Your function performs duplicate work as it checks the string `a`.  To avoid duplicate function calls and greatly improve the performance of your algorithm, you might consider *memoization*.  Otherwise, you could build up a large call stack and potentially cause a [stack overflow error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214741/what-is-a-stackoverflowerror) (hey, that's the name of the website...).

Here's one possible way to implement memoization, by constructing a class around your function:

```
class check:
    def __init__(self):
        self.memo = {}

    def Check(self, a):
        # Base Case
        if len(a) < 2:
            return True

        # Check Memo
        if a in self.memo:
            return self.memo[a]

        # Recursive Call
        if a[0] == a[-1]:
            self.Check(a[1:-1])
        else:
            return False

        # Memoize
        self.memo[a] = True

        return self.Check(a[1:-1])

print check().Check("rats live on no evil star")
```

Comment: I think you should add an end condition when the palindrom is even ("erre" would return false if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: @Pierre.Sassoulas good suggestion; confirming, though, that "erre" returns True as written.

Comment: Upon further examination I think that "a[1:-1]" if 'a' is an array of length 1, return an array of length 0 and does not throw errors, so it works. My bad.

Comment: @Daniel  can you please give an example of duplication in the palindrome example